# Nest a table view into a grouped table view

Tags: swift, ios8, tableview

Good morning everyone,

I am a newbie Swift developer and I would like to receive some advice from experts on how to solve the following problem I am dealing with.

I have a Table View with two sections: the first one contains 4 rows and the second only one. 
I want to display below the second section, a new table view showing some data loaded from Core Data; so far I have dragged and dropped a container view controller embedding a new table view (the one I want to display) and coded the population of this table view in the corresponding TableViewController class I created.

Is there a clever way to embed this nested table within the main table (the one with two sections mentioned before)? Am I following the right path or am I on a completely wrong one? Thanks in advance for your kindness and your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Nested TableViews is not a thing in iOS. You should re-consider your design.
If you need to offer options that depends on a previous selection, you could present a new view (a new "page") with a TableView containing the "sub-options".